# I'm using focusin/ focusout and I'm getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to use the DOM events focusin/focusout but I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at main.js:18
    at main.js:40

I'm using Chrome as my browser in case that helps. Thanks.

```
(function() {

    const body = document.body;
    const input = document.querySelector('input[type=next]');
    const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

    function showFloater() {
        body.classList.add('show-floater');
    }


    function closeFloater() {
        if (body.classList.contains('show-floater')) {
        body.classList.remove('show-floater');
        }
    }

    input.addEventListener('focus', showFloater);
    input.addEventListener('blur', closeFloater);
    overlay.addEventListener('click', closeFloater);    

    // ======= for Showing bookmarks

    const bookmarksList = document.querySelector('.bookmarks-list');
    const bookmarkForm = document.querySelector('.bookmark-form');
    const bookmarkInput = bookmarkForm.querySelector('input[type=text]');

    function createBookmark(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('processing the form');
    }    

    bookmarkForm.addEventListener('submit', createBookmark);    

})();
```

Comment: Is the script *after* the elements it tries to reference? (It needs to be.)

Answer (score 1):

`const input = document.querySelector('input[type=next]');` your **type** is wrong.

I guess you wanna **text**.

`const input = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');`

Comment: Actually this typo was the root of everything. I didn't realize I wrote 'next'. Sorry still new at this.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually this **type**, not this **typo**. You should careness.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (input !== null) {
    input.addEventListener('focus', showFloater);
} else {
    console.log('input not found');
}
```

Always check if you have successfully identified the element using the selector.

Comment: Well that would avoid the error, but it wouldn't help to get the event handler to work...

Comment: A silent "skip if null" like this is probably worse. On one hand, it will avoid an error, but on the other hand, _it will avoid an error_. A simple `document.querySelector` on page load (when in the right place, yada yada) should always work; if it doesn't, I'd want an immediate error because something's really wrong.

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, in order to resolve this issue we need to see the code that associates this function to the event.